# Foundation responsive not works proper?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am using foundation's latest version (5.4.5). I have created a web page that shows a scroll-bar at the bottom. I have added all three types of column classes (`large`, `medium` and `small`), but I'm facing a problem when visiting the site using a smaller device. Help me and Any idea?

Image of my problem:

[image]

Comment: you should post code or make a fiddle so someone can actually see what might be the issue, anyway from the pic it looks like you might some fixed width properties set

Comment: Thanks,i found the same problem that you are presenting.....